# file listing with php ftp_ssl_connect

Tags: php, ftp

I can't get a dir listing in PHP when connecting ftp_ssl_connect.
Works fine in filezilla.

```
<?
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($host,$port,10);
$result = ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $pass);

echo ftp_pwd($conn_id)."\n"; 
var_dump( ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/') );
?>
```

returns:

/

bool(false)

I've also tried with pasv mode but no luck.

It takes a long time after nlist command - it's as if it's timing out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my code is ok and this is probably a firewall or php/openssl issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is ok it's down to a firewall issue.